# On debian 9.1, under xfce4 "ctrl+alt+f1" does nothing except to return from xflock4

Tags: keyboard, debian

after upgrading to 9.1 the ctrl/alt/fx keys do not work anymore.
The only function of "ctrl+alt+f1" is to come back from xflock4 (and this is the only way for that)...
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: as this question is unrelated to programming, and [so] is a *programmer's heaven*, please consider asking on [su].

Comment: I'll do it, thank you.